# Call removeView() on the child's parent first ??

Tags: java, android, view, android-fragmentactivity, fragment-tab-host

```
@ Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.bottom_tabs);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

    // set the Icon
    actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);

    mTabHost = (FragmentTabHost) findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup(this , getSupportFragmentManager() , R.id.realtabcontent);

    tabIndicator1 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.apptheme_tab_indicator_holo , mTabHost.getTabWidget() , false);
    title = (TextView) tabIndicator1.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title.setText("Infos");

    tabIndicator2 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.apptheme_tab_indicator_holo , mTabHost.getTabWidget() , false);
    title = (TextView) tabIndicator2.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title.setText("Info");

    tabIndicator3 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.apptheme_tab_indicator_holo , mTabHost.getTabWidget() , false);
    title = (TextView) tabIndicator3.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title.setText("Development");

    tabIndicator4 = LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.apptheme_tab_indicator_holo , mTabHost.getTabWidget() , false);
    title = (TextView) tabIndicator4.findViewById(android.R.id.title);
    title.setText("Charging");

    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("infos").setIndicator(tabIndicator1) , InformationTabs.class , null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("info").setIndicator(tabIndicator2) , InfoFragment.class , null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("development").setIndicator(tabIndicator3) , DevelopmentTab.class , null);
    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("charging").setIndicator(tabIndicator3) , ChargingTab.class , null);
```

}

LogCat says that the specified child already has a parent. and i should call removeView() on the child`s parent first...

I just don`t get it?!

I know that the problem is that i am using 2 layouts here, but how can i solve it....

Thanks for any hints

Comment: Can you tell us which view you're talking about?

Comment: you are calling setIndicator(tabIndicator3) twice, tabindicator3 cannot have two parents

Comment: private View tabIndicator1 , tabIndicator2 , tabIndicator3 , tabIndicator4;

Comment: haha! Okay took me about 2 hours......thanks a lot :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This kind of error happens when you try to add a view to a parent and it was already added to another.

You're adding `tabIndicator3` two times. Replace this code:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("charging").setIndicator(tabIndicator3) , ChargingTab.class , null);
```

by this:

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("charging").setIndicator(tabIndicator4) , ChargingTab.class , null);
```